# MVC validation on JQuery UI Autocomplete (invalid values)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to validate an autocomplete field using ASP.NET MVC and I have a doubt. I'll describe the scenario below:

Currently, i'm retrieving the values from an Ajax call in the `Form` controller, like this:

```
$("#AutoComplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/form/AjaxCall",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.nome, value: item.nome };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
        });
```

**My `Form` controller:**

```
    public ActionResult AjaxCall(string term)
    {
        var result = (from r in db.Elementoes
                      where r.nome.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                      select new { r.nome }).Distinct();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My View field:

```
@Html.TextBoxAutoCompleteFor(model => model.AutoComplete)
```

Let's suppose that the available values on the autocomplete are: Acre, Piracicaba and Jundiaí

*How can I validate the user's input to the field (client and server-side) and show a validation message like: "the text wasn't found on the database?" Example: If he types Acre it's ok, but if he types Acre3 the error is showed while typing?*

Some points to consider:

1 - I cannot set the autocomplete value to empty if the value isn't correct, i need to show the message.

2 - I cannot set the error class manually in jQuery. I need to use jQuery unobtrusive validation.

I referred to the following articles, but those solutions doesn't worked:

[MVC Autocomplete validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490502/mvc-autocomplete-validation)

[MVC validation with autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978571/mvc-validation-with-autocomplete-field)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just push another array into `result` that contains `status` and then compare the `status` in the `ajax success function` ?

Comment: Hello @Ohgodwhy! Thanks for the response. Sorry, i'm not so familiarized with those components. Can you please give some more detailed information? Thx!